# Nambu Vinogradov bracket

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Has there been any work on homotopy Nambu brackets
or even better on strong homotopy Nambu brackets??
Ordinary Nambu brackets appear most recently in work of Takhtajan.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you could include a tag which wasn't created just for this question...

Comment: You might have noticed that the tags on your question have been removed and that it now only has the (untagged) tag. I have given a more detailed explanation what actually happend [here in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2019/2/23).